# What is Amazon EC2 Bundle Tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is AWS EC2 Bundle Tasks?

[image: Bundle Tasks]

Could any one please help me to understand what it is?

And any one help in showing a sample demo of it by steps or screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

In the old days, before Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS), Amazon EC2 instances were booted from **Instance Store**.

Instance Store is a disk that is directly connected to the host computer, which means that when an instance is turned off, the contents of the disk is lost (because the disk will be assigned to the next user who uses a Virtual Machine on that host).

This also meant that instances could not be stopped and started again, because the boot disk is lost.

These days, Amazon EBS provides network-attached storage, which persists even when an instance is stopped (and, if desired, even after an instance is terminated).

According to this article, **Bundle Tasks** is/was a process designed to get a Windows instance ready for booting from Instance Store:

See: [Bundle Tasks in Amazon | Zeeshan Ali Shah's Blog](http://zeeshanali.com/sysadmin/amazon-bundletasks/)

There is little reason to use this process these days.

Comment: O Thanks a lot Mr. @John . But Could you please say me how to create a bundled task. I dont understand from the document you shared

Comment: I would first ask you to consider _why_ you wish to create it. There are very few reasons to want to do it these days. Even the associated documentation has been removed.

Comment: Just to Learn. Because they are asking that in interview.

Comment: If somebody asked me that in an interview, I would advise them _not_ to use Bundle tasks.

Comment: HAhahahh.. I will try this on my next interview.. I think the bundled Task is not used at present,, Am I right?